# How to modify the editform of a survey?

Tags: survey

I have created a survey. I started sharepoint designer and copied the editform. I opened the new editform, but I do not see all the questions inside my survey. I see only some default 3 questions. How can I see all the questions inside my survey to do some modifications?

I have full control permissions.

[image]